# How to create a function to replace words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with two columns: ORIGIN, DESTINATION

I want to do some replacement.

One is contain 'string' and replace

```
# assume string contains 'UK|Heathrow' is 'London Heathrow Airport'

dis_air.loc[dis_air['ORIGIN'].str.contains('UK|Heathrow'), 'ORIGIN'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'
dis_air.loc[dis_air['DESTINATION'].str.contains('UK|Heathrow'), 'DESTINATION'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'


# assume string contains 'Gatwick' is 'London Gatwick Airport'
dis_air.loc[dis_air['ORIGIN'].str.contains('Gatwick'), 'ORIGIN'] = 'London Gatwick Airport'
dis_air.loc[dis_air['DESTINATION'].str.contains('Gatwick'), 'DESTINATION'] = 'London Gatwick Airport'
```

One is equal to 'string' and replace

```
# assume 'London' is 'Heathrow'
dis_air.ORIGIN_new [dis_air.ORIGIN_new == 'London'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'
dis_air.DESTINATION_new [dis_air.DESTINATION_new == 'London'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'
```

Can some help create two functions, then I can just input a and b two parameters to achieve the outcome. a is string need to be replaced, b is alternative string.

Comment: Can you make it a bit more clear, where exactly you need help, please and maybe also provide some test data? To me it seems, that there is something wrong with `dis_air.ORIGIN_new [dis_air.ORIGIN_new == 'London'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'`. Did you maybe mean: `dis_air.loc[dis_air.ORIGIN_new == 'London', 'ORIGIN_new'] = 'London Heathrow Airport'`?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a function in `pandas` to do this.

```
dis_air['ORIGIN'].replace('UK|Heathrow','London Heathrow Airport',inplace=True)
```